# Why can't I get the first argument of a template like this?

Tags: c++, templates, template-meta-programming, template-argument-deduction

This code

```
template<class>
struct template_arg;

template<class T, template<T> class Template, T Value>
struct template_arg<Template<Value> >
{
    static T value() { return Value; }
};

template<int>
struct const_int { };

int main()
{
    return template_arg<const_int<0> >::value();
}
```

results in the following error:

```
error: template parameters not deducible in partial specialization:
 struct template_arg<Template<Value> >
        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

However, I don't understand why the compiler would be unable to deduce this template parameter.

What is the reason behind this? Is there a nice/generic workaround?

Comment: Template template and template value arguments are second class citizens.  Support for them honestly sucks, so much that I use proxy types for both when I want to do serious metaprogramming.

Comment: [Compiles fine](https://wandbox.org/permlink/Ap4P8Qt5Fi7lheCi) in C++17. The deduction rules for template template parameter changed.

Comment: @liliscent - you're right... my compiler is to old for a good C++17 support.

Comment: Oh wow, I didn't realize that. @liliscent: Consider posting an answer?

Comment: @Yakk: How would you use a proxy type here though? I'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: @mehrdad use types for template value parameters.  Use types for template template parameters.  Requires work, but makes metaprogramming sane.

Comment: @Yakk: You mean like the `const_int` which I already had here?

Comment: @mehr yes.  Now add `constexpr int operator() const{return v;}` and the like.

Comment: [Workaround](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b10606901ab31fe4).